# Is there a calendar that can select a range of dates in google closure library

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-closure, google-closure-library

in my project I'm using google closure. Is there in google closure any calendar component that allows selecting range of dates?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but there is a [DatePicker UI](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_ui_DatePicker.html) component. To have a range selection, you would need to subclass that component to implement your own functionality. Alternately you could use two of them and have the first datepicker select the first date in the range, and the second datepicker pick the second date, but you will still need to coordinate events between the two.